Creating a Comparative Performance Analysis Table with Filters in AWS QuickSight
I am a beginner in using Amazon QuickSight, and I have a dataset containing information about tasks performed by groups, including a performance score for each task. My goal is to create a table that allows users to compare the performance scores between any two selected categories or groups.
The table should have the following columns:

Task
Performance Score for the category selected from the first dropdown filter
Performance Score for the category selected from the second dropdown filter
Absolute Difference between the Performance Scores of the two selected categories


To facilitate this comparison, I plan to include two dropdown filters that allow users to select a unique category from each filter. The table should dynamically update to display the performance scores for the selected categories and calculate the absolute difference between them.
Additionally, I would like to incorporate calculated fields or expressions to derive other performance comparison metrics, such as relative difference, if possible.
Comparative analysis table:

My question is: How can I implement this comparative performance analysis table with filters and calculated fields in Amazon QuickSight?
I have created two drop-down filters such that they both display all the groups/categories. But I'm not sure how to reference the selected values from these filters and also how to display only the performance metrics for those two selected groups in the final comparative analysis table.
